# How to achieve immediate redirect to page before home page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, redirect, video

I am converting a Wordpress website to Magento. One aspect of this switch is achieving a Video Intro into the website. Currently it utilizes a Wordpress plugin which loads a website http://example.com/video-intro before http://example.com and after the video is finished playing the window is redirected to http://example.com.

I have purchased the pure PHP version of this plugin (documentation here: http://plugins.themestrike.com/videointro2/documentation-php/), but it does not seem to work with Magento. I cannot figure out why. The page http://example.com/video-intro works great, the redirect works great, but I cannot get http://example.com/video-intro to come up before anything else. *The plugin creator has responded as unable to provide any support for the script.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you could do 2 things:

1. use a php header function to redirect the home page to the page you wish - more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
2. Alter your .htaccess file to always re-direct users to the video link.

However it is worth considering what do you do when considering repeat users who have already seen the video.

Comment: With either of these answers, will this allow someone to:

1. Open http://example.com
2. Be redirected to http://example.com/video-intro
3. Be redirected to http://example.com which will not result in another redirect?

I currently have this working via a Wordpress plugin at http://impactgel.com/

Comment: That's where the php header comes into place, as for that session you can do the following based on a session or a cookie:

Create a variable to false
Set an IF statement to say that if false, re-direct to this header location and set the variable to true,
And obviously if the variable is already true, it will not redirect to the video.